# Root kit advice on ubuntu

Tags: malware, rootkit

I've been a Windows user for many years but recently Avast was bringing up 100's of Rootkit infected files. So I decided to make the switch to Ubuntu to wipe everything, and I’m quite enjoying the change.

But I'm still quite paranoid about any possible rootkit infection. I had to download and burn a Ubuntu install CD from my infected laptop at the time, I have a feeling this probably wasn't the best idea but it's my only computer.

I completely wiped the hard drive when installing ubuntu, but I keep reading about rootkits that reside in the kernel or the network card. Is there anyway to check if my laptop is still infected?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install rkhunter` [rkhunter.sourceforge.net](http://rkhunter.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, welcome to a free world. Second, yes, there is still a possibility that the hardware you have is infected, as you did not explain where or how you "wiped everything" on the drive. Rootkits that reside at the hardware layer (if you were truly infected with Rootkits, it is important to know which rootkit was installed and where in the system) are much harder to remove from the system and may require replacement of hardware if the rootkit was installed at the firmware layer.

I point you to the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rootkit) which explains some of this, and might be beneficial herein. There are numerous rootkit detectors, but the effectiveness is always subject to the ability to truly detect malware and where/when the rootkit is loaded. If loaded in firmware, suspect that you need new equipment.

It is much harder to infect or attack Linux system due to the diversity of installations, partitioning and methods of securing the instances. There is no "single model" approach, which is why the level of difficulty is significantly more challenging to attack. Not that it is impossible, it is possible, but rather it may not bring the same "bang for the buck" that malware authors want to focus on.

Since we do not know what rootkit was installed, where it was installed and what it effected on the system, I would treat it as "untrustworthy" as you do not know where the rootkit lie in the system.

[Darik's Boot and Nuke](http://www.dban.org/download) is perhaps the best hard-drive wiping tool that you can choose, but it takes patience to allow it to completely wipe the drive. This still does not insure that any rootkit that may have infected firmware is removed though. The likelihood of a Windows rootkit compromising a Linux system is pretty slim to none, unless it was written into the firmware, BIOS or other pre-boot hardware that gives it full control over the system regardless of the OS installed.

My advice would be to have the system examined by someone who really understands same, and figure out how that rootkit was installed and prevent that avenue of access from recurring.

As for Linux, [chkrootkit](http://www.chkrootkit.org/), [rkhunter](http://rootkit.nl/projects/rootkit_hunter.html), [maldetect](https://www.rfxn.com/projects/linux-malware-detect/) and other offerings exist (some commercial). They help prevent and detect malware and rootkits, and they are generally effective. However, having stated that I would not start with known bad hardware unless I was certain of totally ridding myself of the rootkit first, and event then, I would replace the drive as it is always suspect.

Do hope this is helpful information. Have a nice day.